# Web scraper replacing some characters with question marks

Tags: c#, character-encoding, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I make a simple web scraper that scrapes lyrics for me then writes it to a database. everything works but for some reason it's replacing some characters with question marks and when I view this information on a simple php web page I'm seeing a lot of mistakes in the lyrics.

```
I?m = I'm
Let?s = Let's
haven?t = haven't
stuff like that.
```

I know the error is in c# and my code because I put a breakpoints before it writes to the database and I display it in a rich text box. How would I get it to display these characters correctly?

```
        public static string getSourceCode(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            resp.Close();
            return sourceCode;
        }
........
string url = txbURL2.Text;

string sourceCode = sourceCode = WorkerClass.getSourceCode(url);
int startIndex = sourceCode.IndexOf("<td valign=\"top\" width=\"100%\">");
sourceCode = sourceCode.Substring(startIndex, sourceCode.Length - startIndex);
........
//Gets Lyric
startIndex = sourceCode.IndexOf("<br><b>Lyrics:</b><br><br>") + 30;
endIndex = sourceCode.IndexOf("     <br><br>", startIndex);
string lyric = sourceCode.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex) + "";
rtbLyric.Text = lyric;
//End Lyric
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably character encoding.  My guess is that the web page you're scraping is encoded in UTF8, but somewhere along the line you're converting to ASCII.

Check out the excellent article called "[What every developer should know about character encoding](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2009/11/what-every-developer-should-know-about-character-encoding.html)" for more details.

**Update**

You could try this, although the `StreamReader` should default to UTF-8 anyway:

```
var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), encoding);
```

Comment: Is there anyway of converting it back to UTF8 or keeping it UTF8? I'm very new to programming. So, everything you guys are saying I'll have to research it and learn.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code you've posted.  C# generally operates with UTF8 encoding by default.  See my update for a suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding by searching for charset in the html code.
Your code snipplet misses the actual load process, so it is impossible to tell where it goes wrong.

Comment: I added what I believe you said I was missing.

Comment: I was unable to fine any <meta> information for the charset. what is the default for html? is it UTF8?

Comment: Which HTML version is your document? Check also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the WebClient:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
string html = client.DownloadString(url);
```